# Extend Child Class of one plugin into another plugin

Tags: php, function, class, overriding, extend

I am using [Plugin: Visualizer: Charts and Graphs]
In this plugin there is class

```
class Visualizer_Module_Frontend extends Visualizer_Module {
```

`const NAME = __CLASS__;

private $_charts = array();

public function __construct( Visualizer_Plugin $plugin ) {
    parent::__construct( $plugin );

    $this->_addAction( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueueScripts' );
    $this->_addShortcode( 'visualizer', 'renderChart' );

    // add do_shortocde hook for widget_text filter
    if ( !has_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
    }

    // add do_shortcode hook for term_description filter
    if ( !has_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
    }
}


public function enqueueScripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'visualizer-google-jsapi', '//www.google.com/jsapi', array(), null, true );
    wp_register_script( 'visualizer-render', VISUALIZER_ABSURL . 'js/render.js', array( 'visualizer-google-jsapi', 'jquery' ), Visualizer_Plugin::VERSION, true );
}


public function renderChart( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'     => false, // chart id
        'class'  => false, // chart class
        'series' => false, // series filter hook            
        'data'   => false, // data filter hook          
        'settings'   => false, // data filter hook
    ), $atts );

    // if empty id or chart does not exists, then return empty string
    if ( !$atts['id'] || !( $chart = get_post( $atts['id'] ) ) || $chart->post_type != Visualizer_Plugin::CPT_VISUALIZER ) {
        return '';
    }

    $id = 'visualizer-' . $atts['id']; 
    $class = apply_filters( Visualizer_Plugin::FILTER_CHART_WRAPPER_CLASS, $atts['class'], $atts['id'] );
    $class = !empty( $class ) ? ' class="' . $class . '"' : '';

    $type = get_post_meta( $chart->ID, Visualizer_Plugin::CF_CHART_TYPE, true );

    // faetch and update settings
    $settings = get_post_meta( $chart->ID, Visualizer_Plugin::CF_SETTINGS, true );
    if ( empty( $settings['height'] ) ) {
        $settings['height'] = '400';
    }

    // handle series filter hooks
    $series = apply_filters( Visualizer_Plugin::FILTER_GET_CHART_SERIES, get_post_meta( $chart->ID, Visualizer_Plugin::CF_SERIES, true ), $chart->ID, $type );
    if ( !empty( $atts['series'] ) ) {
        $series = apply_filters( $atts['series'], $series, $chart->ID, $type );         
    }
    // handle settings filter hooks
    $settings = apply_filters( Visualizer_Plugin::FILTER_GET_CHART_SETTINGS, $settings, $chart->ID, $type );
    if ( !empty( $atts['settings'] ) ) {
        $settings = apply_filters( $atts['settings'], $settings, $chart->ID, $type );
    }

    // handle data filter hooks
    $data = apply_filters( Visualizer_Plugin::FILTER_GET_CHART_DATA, unserialize( $chart->post_content ), $chart->ID, $type );
    if ( !empty( $atts['data'] ) ) {
        $data = apply_filters( $atts['data'], $data, $chart->ID, $type );
                }

    // add chart to the array
    $this->_charts[$id] = array(
        'type'     => $type,
        'series'   => $series,
        'settings' => $settings,
        'data'     => $data,
    );

    // enqueue visualizer render and update render localizations
    wp_enqueue_script( 'visualizer-render' );
    wp_localize_script( 'visualizer-render', 'visualizer', array( 'charts' => $this->_charts ) );

    return '<div id="' . $id . '"' . $class . '></div>';
} }`

I want to extent this class so that i can override the function renderChart().
But I want to do this with another custom plugin.

Comment: I dont want any editing in [Plugin: Visualizer: Charts and Graphs]. whatever to do do should be in another custom plugin .